# I want to use pixel coordinates in my shader

Tags: coordinates, pixel, webgl2

From https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html

> WebGL2 adds the ability to read a texture using pixel coordinates as well. Which way is best is up to you. I feel like it's more common to use texture coordinates than pixel coordinates.

Nowhere is this mentioned other then passing uniform with texture dimensions in pixels and calculate from there, is there a way to access these pixel coords without calculation as it is supposed here?

Answer (score 0):

You can read individual pixels/texels from a texture in WebGL2 with `texelFetch`

```
vec4 color = texelFetch(someUniformSampler, ivec2(pixelX, pixelY), intMipLevel);
```

For example, compute the average color of a texture by reading each pixel

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D tex;
out vec4 outColor;
void main() {
  int level = 0;
  ivec2 size = textureSize(tex, level);
  vec4 color = vec4(0);
  for (int y = 0; y < size.y; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; ++x) {
      color += texelFetch(tex, ivec2(x, y), level);
    }
  }
  outColor = color / float(size.x * size.y);
}
`;

function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  gl.canvas.width = 1;
  gl.canvas.height = 1;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);

  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  // so we don't need mips
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  // so we can pass a non multiple of 4 bytes
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  
  const values = new Uint8Array([10, 255, 13, 70, 56, 45, 89]);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R8, values.length, 1, 0, gl.RED, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, values);
  
  gl.useProgram(prg);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  
  const gpuAverage = new Uint8Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gpuAverage);
  
  const jsAverage = values.reduce((s, v) => s + v) / values.length;
  
  console.log('gpuAverage:', gpuAverage[0]);
  console.log('jsAverage:', jsAverage);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

notes: since the canvas is RGBA8 can only get integer result. Could change to some float format but that would complicate the example which is not about rendering it's about `texelFetch`.

Of course just by changing the data from R8 to RGBA8 we can do 4 arrays as once if we interleave the values

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D tex;
out vec4 outColor;
void main() {
  int level = 0;
  ivec2 size = textureSize(tex, level);
  vec4 color = vec4(0);
  for (int y = 0; y < size.y; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; ++x) {
      color += texelFetch(tex, ivec2(x, y), level);
    }
  }
  outColor = color / float(size.x * size.y);
}
`;

function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  gl.canvas.width = 1;
  gl.canvas.height = 1;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);

  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  // so we don't need mips
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  // so we can pass a non multiple of 4 bytes
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  
  const values = new Uint8Array([
     10, 100, 200, 1,
     12, 150, 231, 9,
     50, 129, 290, 3,
     45, 141, 300, 2,
     12, 123, 212, 4,
  ]);
  const width = 1;
  const height = values.length / 4;
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA8, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, values);
  
  gl.useProgram(prg);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  
  const gpuAverages = new Uint8Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gpuAverages);
  
  let jsAverages = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (let i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      jsAverages[j] += values[i * 4 + j];
    }
  }
  jsAverages = jsAverages.map(v => v / height);
  
  console.log('gpuAverage:', gpuAverages.join(', '));
  console.log('jsAverage:', jsAverages.join(', '));
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

To do more requires figuring out some way to arrange the data and use an input to the fragment shader to figure out where the data is. For example we again interleave the data, 5 arrays so the data goes 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4.

Let's go back to R8 and do 5 separate arrays. We need to draw 5 pixels. We can tell which pixel is being drawn by looking at `gl_FragCoord`. We can use that to offset which pixels we look at and pass in how many to skip.

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 100.0;
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform int numArrays;
out vec4 outColor;
void main() {
  int level = 0;
  int start = int(gl_FragCoord.x);
  ivec2 size = textureSize(tex, level);
  vec4 color = vec4(0);
  for (int y = 0; y < size.y; ++y) {
    for (int x = start; x < size.x; x += numArrays) {
      color += texelFetch(tex, ivec2(x, y), level);
    }
  }
  outColor = color / float(size.x / numArrays * size.y);
}
`;

function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  const numArraysLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "numArrays");
  
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  // so we don't need mips
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  // so we can pass a non multiple of 4 bytes
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  
  const numArrays = 5;
  const values = new Uint8Array([
     10, 100, 200, 1, 70,
     12, 150, 231, 9, 71,
     50, 129, 290, 3, 90,
     45, 141, 300, 2, 80,
     12, 123, 212, 4, 75,
  ]);
  const width = values.length;
  const height = 1;
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R8, width, height, 0, gl.RED, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, values);
  
  gl.canvas.width = numArrays;
  gl.canvas.height = 1;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, numArrays, 1);

  gl.useProgram(prg);
  gl.uniform1i(numArraysLoc, numArrays);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  
  const gpuData = new Uint8Array(4 * numArrays);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, numArrays, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gpuData);
  const gpuAverages = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numArrays; ++i) {
    gpuAverages.push(gpuData[i * 4]); // because we're only using the RED channel
  }
  const jsAverages = (new Array(numArrays)).fill(0);
  const numValues = (width / numArrays) * height;
  for (let i = 0; i < width / numArrays; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numArrays; ++j) {
      jsAverages[j] += values[i * numArrays + j] / numValues;
    }
  }
  
  console.log('gpuAverage:', gpuAverages.join(', '));
  console.log('jsAverage:', jsAverages.join(', '));
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thats amazing, I see it is "rendering" the color of a single pixel in the canvas, lets say there are 2 arrays (could be an input texture with n widht and 2 pixel height) and I want to calculate 2 averages in parallel , this mean the output texture needs to be 2 pixels in size so the GPU will call the fragment shader in parralel for each of the 2 output pixels?

Comment: oh wait, this means i need the canvas.length x canvas.height needs to be 2 pixels area size, the only thing  needed is to pass somehow to the fragment shader wich array to work on , i guess this needs to be done by the vertex shader

Comment: it doesn't need to be done by the vertex shader in this case. you just need to arrange the data in some way to make it easy to access per result you want.

Comment: absoluutly fantastic, especially the last example, awesome!

Comment: Hi, if the gl context is not referenced anymore (JS garbage collector), are all the gpu buffers, uniforms, textures also automaticly deleted from the gpu hardware?

Comment: If I change the "gl_PointSize" to 1.0 the example produces mostly zeros, why is that?

Comment: gl_PointSize is in pixels. If you set it to 1 only 1 pixel is going to be draw for the 1 point we're drawing. I used `gl_PointSize` and draw with `gl.POINTS` and a single point because it's absolute simplest shader to show off some feature unrelated to buffers and attributes and vertex shader. In the case above things will work as long as `gl_PointSize` is larger than or equal to the size of the area you're trying to draw to (except for the fact that there is a maximum point size) https://webglstats.com/webgl2/parameter/ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying, one pixel per point, per point of what?. the destination canvas is 1x5 thats 5 pixels right? so need 5 points? dont we have 5 points?

Comment: When you call `gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, offset, count);` it draws `count` points. You can set the size each point is drawn by setting `gl_PointSize` in the vertex shader. Each point is effectively drawn as a square -gl_PointSize/2 to +gl_PointSize in pixels in both dimensions (horizontal and vertical). Where the center is is defined by whatever you put in `gl_Position`.

Comment: "-gl_PointSize/2 to +gl_PointSize" makes no sense to me
Do you men  for then nth point  (n)*gl_PointSize to (n+1)gl_PointSize  with the  gl_Position (n+1/2)*gl_PointSize  ?

Comment: Ask a new question

Comment: Ok, i asked a new question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457035/the-relation-between-gl-pointsize-gl-position-gl-fragcoord