# three.js - why does it appear that multiple pixels have the same gl_FragCoord.xy?

Tags: three.js

According to the [khronos group documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml), `gl_FragCoord` specifies any location *within* the pixel being shaded.

Below I have a shader which colors a pixel based on its coordinates modulo 2. We could expect to see a fine-grain checkerboard-like pattern where each pixel has a color different from each of its neighbors. However, it looks like most of the pixels' `gl_FragCoord.xy` is not the coordinates in units of pixels, but instead it appears that the value is a non-integer that is some *scaling* of the pixel coordinates.

```js
var canvas;
var scene;
var renderer;
var camera;
var shader;
var quad;

function init() {

  let div = document.getElementById('div');
 
  let newCanvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
  newCanvas.id = 'canvas';
  let height = 360;
  newCanvas.style.height = height + 'px';
  let width = 1440;
  newCanvas.style.width  = width + 'px';
  newCanvas.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  newCanvas.style['border-radius'] = '12px';
  div.appendChild(newCanvas);
  div.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));

  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-0.5*width, 0.5*width, -0.5*height, 0.5*height, 1, 1000);


  shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: 'void main() { gl_Position = vec4(position,1); }',
    fragmentShader: 'void main(){ gl_FragColor = vec4(mod(gl_FragCoord.xy, 2.0), 0, 1); }'
  });

  quad = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height), shader);

  scene.add(quad);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

var button = document.getElementById('start');
button.onclick = function() { init(); animate(); }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.js"></script>
  <div align="center" id="div">
  <button type="button" id="start" class="button" >Start</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It probably seems odd that I used a very wide canvas and that the canvas was appended to the document after a button was clicked, but this is how it is implemented in the application that I'm working on, so I thought that perhaps these features might be causing the problem somehow.

This is a strange problem that I've never come across before, so I haven't really come up with any way to try to debug it. The only thing I've tried so far was changing the height and width of the quad, but that didn't change the output at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The problem was quite simple: the renderer was not set to the correct size (I thought the default size was the size of the canvas, but apparently I was wrong).

Adding

```
renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, false);
```

after the declaration of the renderer solves the problem.

```js
var canvas;
var scene;
var renderer;
var camera;
var shader;
var quad;

function init() {

  let div = document.getElementById('div');
 
  let newCanvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
  newCanvas.id = 'canvas';
  let height = 360;
  newCanvas.style.height = height + 'px';
  let width = 1440;
  newCanvas.style.width  = width + 'px';
  newCanvas.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  newCanvas.style['border-radius'] = '12px';
  div.appendChild(newCanvas);
  div.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));

  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
  renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, false);
  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-0.5*width, 0.5*width, -0.5*height, 0.5*height, 1, 1000);


  shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: 'void main() { gl_Position = vec4(position,1); }',
    fragmentShader: 'void main(){ gl_FragColor = vec4(mod(gl_FragCoord.xy, 2.0), 0, 1); }'
  });

  quad = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height), shader);

  scene.add(quad);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

var button = document.getElementById('start');
button.onclick = function() { init(); animate(); }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.js"></script>
  <div align="center" id="div">
  <button type="button" id="start" class="button" >Start</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: [`gl_FragCoord` is not integer values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457035/the-relation-between-gl-pointsize-gl-position-gl-fragcoord)